# How to wait until receiving multiple websocket responses send in sequence, for a single request sent, using JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I am using the Jmeter WebSocket Sampler. I have successfully connected to the websocket, and can send a json request. It is a chat bot, and I will be validating it's response.
However, I have observed in websocket log, the websocket responds to the json request with a short confirmation response before the actual response.
for example, the first response is {"event":joingame,} where the response is {"event":"game"}. I don't really need this information.
Only then is the real response sent (as I observed in webscoket log)
 I have tried the general Websocket Sampler.
The websocket responses come in "frames", each having a JSON response, my samplers are closing right after the first frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to switch to the [WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

This way you will be able to establish a connection first:

[image]

and then continue reading the frames re-using the connection unless you find the frame with the content you're looking for:

[image]

It makes sense to use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) in order to continue reading until the anticipated text appears in the response.

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide/)